# Use DISM on different parition

Tags: windows, dism

I am trying to repair a corrupted windows installation which is on a separate local drive `d:` using DISM but I cannot find any information on how to run DISM to a repair a windows installation which is on a separate drive.

How can I run the following command on drive `d:`

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

Comment: have you tried it? Does it work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`/Online` means the current running Windows. If you want to serve a different windows, use the `Image` parameter:

```
dism /Image:D:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this command: DISM.exe /Image=D:\ /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth  then I hit enter. The HDD I was running dism on was in a docking station, connected by usb cable. Hope this helps?